# Change view style in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: css, custom, view-styles

I've been running around in circles for the past two days trying to figure this out:

How would one go about changing the style of a document list inside a web part app?

The picture below demonstrates the current view, and what I'm looking to achieve:

[image]

I've looked at trying to:

- Make a custom view style - (still lost on that one).
- Using JSLink - Not ideal.
- Making a custom theme?
- Adding custom css - Not ideal as we need multiple different layouts
  across the site.

A really simply-written answer is what I'm looking for, I'm new to sharepoint and the documentation is very confusing.

Thanks!

Comment: Use JSLink to create your custom view. See http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2013/01/using-jslink-to-change-ui-of-sharepoint_20.html